# How to save my locale language even after restarting my app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am getting the default language after restarting my app but i want to get the upadated langauge

`

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return GetMaterialApp(
      translations:  LocalString(),
      locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
      home:  homeScreen();
```

`

Comment: You must store the selected language in user phone, for more information plase read this: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Comment: Use shared preferences to store the locale https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared preferences to store the locale then retrieve that stored locale value from shared preferences wherever you need.

Answer (score 1):

When an user picks a language, in GetX you can update the locale using the following function:

```
void changeLang(String lang) {
    Locale locale = Locale(lang);
    Get.updateLocale(locale);
  }
```

You can use the above function in the following ways:

```
changeLang('en')
```

or

```
changeLang('bn')
```

So, after the user has changed language you can store it in GetStorage(https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) and retrieve it later.

After importing the GetStorage package. Add the following line before runApp(const MyApp());

```
await GetStorage.init();
```

After initialising getstorage, you can save your locale using the following code:

```
 Future<bool> saveLanguage(String? lang) async {
    final box = GetStorage();
    await box.write('lang', lang);
    return true;
  }
```

To retrieve the saved language, you can use the following code:

```
  String? getLang() {
    final box = GetStorage();
    return box.read('lang');
  }
```

So, when user re-runs app, check if getLang() is null or not. If it is not null you can use the following code to update your locale accordingly:

```
if(getLang() != null) {
      Locale locale = Locale(getLang()!);
      Get.updateLocale(locale);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

In my experience, use a singleton. Example:

```
class PrefsInstance {
  static PrefsInstance _instance = new PrefsInstance.internal();

  PrefsInstance.internal();

  factory PrefsInstance() => _instance;

  Future<void> saveAccessToken(String token) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print("saveAccessToken");

    await prefs.setBool(GeneralPrefsConstant.PREF_KEY_LOGIN, true);
    await prefs.setString(GeneralPrefsConstant.PREF_KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, token);
    DataInstance().isLogin = true;
    DataInstance().accessToken = token;
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print("LOG OUT -> FIX SHARED PREFERENCES");

    await prefs.setBool(GeneralPrefsConstant.PREF_KEY_LOGIN, false);
    await prefs.setString(GeneralPrefsConstant.PREF_KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN, "");
    await prefs.setString(GeneralPrefsConstant.PREF_KEY_PROFILE, "");
    DataInstance().isLogin = false;
    DataInstance().accessToken = "";
  }

  saveLanguage() async {...}
}
```

The shared preference variables will be saved into your phone's memory and won't disappear when you close the app. Each variable has specific key (`GeneralPrefsConstant`). It's every easy to use. If you want to save, use asynchronous method `setString(key, value)`. If you want to get, use `getString(key)` (not async). If your app was installed the first time, it could be nullable when get shared preference, so it is necessary to check carefully.

Good luck.